# Strange PlatformException on iOS FWFEvaluateJavaScriptError with WebView

Tags: ios, flutter, webview, wkwebview

I've released a Flutter iOS app where I need to inject JavaScript to workaround a bug in Flutter (I don't have a link to that bug right now). Fact is that you don't get updates when the url has changed when you use the `window.pushstate()` API.

I build a small hack to get informed about changes, but that seems to cause exceptions. Since I have just this crazy short stacktrace I am not sure how I can fix it.

```
PlatformException: PlatformException(FWFEvaluateJavaScriptError, Failed evaluating JavaScript., Instance of 'NSError', null)
  File "web_kit_api_impls.dart", line 1013, in WKWebViewHostApiImpl.evaluateJavaScriptForInstances
  File "<asynchronous suspension>"
  File "webkit_webview_controller.dart", line 278, in WebKitWebViewController.runJavaScript
```

I think the relevant code here is where I build my webviewcontroller:

```dart
final pushStateSpyJavaScript = '''((history)=>{
  const org=history.pushState;
  history.pushState=(state,_,url)=>{
    org.apply(history, [state,_,url]);
    if(url) {
      window.flutter.postMessage(url.toString());
    }
  };
  addEventListener('popstate', (event) => window.flutter.postMessage(location.href.toString()));
})(window.history)''';

webViewController.addJavaScriptChannel('flutter', onMessageReceived: (message) {
  onUrlChanged(message.message);
});

webViewController.setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
  onPageFinished: (url) {
    onUrlChanged(url);
    webViewController.runJavaScript(pushStateSpyJavaScript);
  },
));
```

Do you see something oblivious wrong? I got multiple hunderes of that exceptions above.

Since I am no native iOS developer I am not sure how can I debug this.